# sistema de favoritos sin base datos

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero hacer un botón de favoritos,como un corazón o algo así...el tema es que no quería utilizar base de datos y he encontrado un código que funciona y me gusta pero al salir y volver a entrar se reinicia y borra los datos:

```js
var likes =0;
     function like(){
     document.getElementById("show").innerHTML=likes;
     likes=likes+1;
}
```

```css
#button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>me gusta</title>
   </head>
   <body>

    <button id="button" onClick="like()">LIKE</button>
    <p type="text" style="color:blue;"id="show"></p>
    <h2>LIKES</h2>
    </body>
    </html>
```

¿Cómo lo puedo hacer para que se guarde sin usar base datos?

Comment: Hola, podrías guardar los datos en un archivo `txt` y leerlos al entrar de nuevo a la pagina.

Comment: Podrías usar la api de [Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage)

Comment: Gracias @the-breaker ¿Y como lo hago? también lo he intentado pero no lo imprimía...Gracias por responder

Comment: @KacosPro he estado mirando lo de la api....pero no lo entiendo...por eso buscaba algo sencillo. Gracias por responder

Comment: @AlfredoMarquez, si en un par de minutos no hallas una respuesta te la doy con gusto. (A veces otros usuarios se me adelantan y dan la misma respuesta que iba a proponer).

Comment: @the-breaker gracias!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar localStorage para guardar

```
var likes =0;
     function like(){
     document.getElementById("show").innerHTML=likes;
     likes=likes+1;
localStorage.setItem('likes', likes);

}
```

proba que se guarda:

```
console.log(localStorage.getItem('likes'));
```

Comment: Gracias @x-rw por responder!1 no me funciona.... lo he puesto así

Comment: no funciona...lo puse asi:      <script type="text/javascript">
var likes =0;
     function like(){
     document.getElementById("show").innerHTML=likes;
     likes=likes+1;
localStorage.setItem('likes', likes);

}
console.log(localStorage.getItem('likes'));

</script>   ¿Está bien?

Comment: @AlfredoMarquez, coloca `var likes =localStorage.getItem('likes')*1;` en lugar de `var likes =0;` y te saldrá.

Comment: perfecto!! al recargar la pagina desaparece y al hacer clik me muestra la suma total...¿Hay forma de que muestre la suma total fija?

Comment: @AlfredoMarquez, coloca `document.getElementById("show").innerHTML=likes;` debajo de la linea anterior y eso es todo.

Comment: @the-breaker Ahora no lee nada.....var likes =localStorage.getItem('likes')*1;
document.getElementById("show").innerHTML=likes;
function like(){

likes=likes+1;
localStorage.setItem('likes', likes);
}
console.log(localStorage.getItem('likes'));

Comment: @the-breaker y en  en un archivo txt como me comentabas es más facil?

Comment: @AlfredoMarquez, primero, jeje, no cambies de lugar esa linea, debes repetirla así: `var likes =localStorage.getItem('likes');
  document.getElementById("show").innerHTML=likes;

  function like(){
     document.getElementById("show").innerHTML=likes;
     likes=likes+1;
     localStorage.setItem('likes', likes);
  }` y segundo la para hacerla con un archivo debes hacerla del lado del servidor (usando php por ejemplo), es un poquito difícil.

Comment: @the-breaker vale¡¡ perfecto, como te puedo valorar  la ayuda?

Comment: @AlfredoMarquez, no te preocupes, para eso es la pagina.

Comment: pues GRACIAS ;)

Comment: @the-breaker los puntos deberian ser tuyos, tu le ayudaste totalmente.